# JavaScript variable assignment not working

Tags: javascript

I have run in to a stupid problem...
I declared a new variable called leadingZero. I save the modified .js file and run the project with a breakpoint on the leadingZero assignment and in watcher window it says its undefined after passing this line, but all the other declarations here are working fine and I can see the assigned values. needless to say the getObject call does not work now.

```
var leadingZero = 0; //new variable
var chkActive; 
var chkSubscribe; 
var hdnItem = getObject('hdnItemCounter');
var ItemCount = parseInt(hdnItem.value) + 1;

for (intCounter = 2; intCounter <= ItemCount; intCounter++) {
  chkActive = getObject('dgrProductList_ctl0' + leadingZero + intCounter + '_chkActive');
}
```

Comment: It's defined every time I run your code subbing in a noop for `getObject`

Comment: When presenting JavaScript issues a working sample on jsfiddle.net as well as indicating platform and browser make debugging and answering a whole lot easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be changes to the js were not loaded in ie cache. even after closing ie, rebuilding the project and running again, I still need to hit ctrl+f5 on the page to load the new javascript

Comment: The question should have mentioned that the problem was only appearing in IE then, just like Marc Gagne commented and this should have been added as a comment not as an answer. But hopefully now you know to always kill that cache before looking for bugs :)

Answer (score 2):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/DHDsE/

Not getting the undefined problem tho, but having to add toString() to leadingZero for it to render in the console.log, so maybe that's your issue too.

Comment: i can use this piece you provided var hdnItem = {
    value: 3
};

Answer (score 1):

You did set the breakpoint on the line below, didn't you?

Because if you set it on the line `var leadingZero = 0;` it halts before the line is evaluated, which explains the undefined value in the watcher.

Also, as gillesc pointed out, your `leadingZero` must be a string, otherwise you're adding up `intCounter` and `leadingZero`, rather than concatenating them.